# How to read a dynamic text using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to get the dynamic text ie. being displayed on a webpage when password input is wrong on form submit using Selenium Python.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="center" height="20">
                    <div id="information" align="center" style="color:red;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="information" align="center" style="color:red;">Password is incorrect!!</div>
```

In the above code, I tried to retrieve the text "Password is incorrect!!" which is being displayed when input password in wrong on form submit using below code.

```
pwd_input_result_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='information']")
pwd_input_result_info = pwd_input_result_element.text
```

But when i print pwd_input_result_info this displays empty.

How to proceed further to retrieve the dynamic text "Password is incorrect!!" using Selenium Python?

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,
>
> I am able to retrieve the dynamic text "Password is incorrect!!" when
>   we submit a form with wrong password input using below code.
>
> We need to wait for a specific element for the text to appear when we
>   input wrong password and submit.
>
> Here is my code snippet which works fine.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# check whether the password input is correct or not
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
            (By.XPATH, "//div[@id='information'][@style='color:red;']"), "Password is 
incorrect!!"))

        print("Invalid Login")
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Valid Login")

    pwd_input_result_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='information'] 
[@style='color:red;']")
    pwd_input_result = pwd_input_result_element.text
    print(pwd_input_result_element.text)
    print("pwd_input_result:", pwd_input_result)
```